# Imghost different errors

Tags: php

When i try to upload a picture in Imghost script i upload it and then i got error

```
**Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/****/public_html/config.php:1) in /home/*****/public_html/upload.php on line 20**
```

That is show in the line 20 require_once('config.php');

> $dbconnect = new db(); $dbconnect->connect(); session_start(); if
>   **(UPLOAD_ONLY_REGISTERED == 1) {**
>       if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
>           header('Location: register.php');
>           exit();
>       } } ?>

Also i try to log in the admin panel and get this

```
**Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/*****/public_html/config.php:1) in /home/****/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 210**

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/****/public_html/config.php:1) in /home/****/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 255**
```

The whole file of the function.php http://justpaste.it/dt6w

How to fix these errors?

Comment: whats line 1 of **config.php**

Comment: you need to fix 1st line of config.php as it says in error message, check that config.php starts exactly with `<?php` without any spaces or unicode marks before this (check file via any hex editor)

Comment: This is shown in the 1st line of config.php 
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/135O

Comment: @user3093043 it is not original file, it is copy-pasted content of it, where unicode file marks are lost, check your local file with hex editor, and I'm 99% sure that you will see 2-3 "invisible" bytes before `<?php`, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @IlyaBursov WORKED! LIKE YOU WROTE! Thank you!

Comment: One problem is fixed now it remains one more problem. 

When i try to upload a picture in Imghost script i upload it and then i got error

    **Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/****/public_html/config.php:1) in /home/*****/public_html/upload.php on line 20**


The whole code of the upload.php http://justpaste.it/dt70 

How to fix this?